# Did Jesus promise Judas a powerful position in the future kingdom of God?

Tags: life-of-jesus

Jesus told his disciples that, in the new Kingdom of God, they would sit upon twelve thrones judging the twelve tribes of Israel. Matthew 19:28, Luke 22:30. Didn't Jesus know that Judas was going to betray him.  So did Jesus offer a throne to Judas?  If so why?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Matthew 19:28 reads *you who have followed me*, and Luke 22:30 has *those who have stood by me in my trials*; not sure how Judas would qualify for any.

Comment: @Lucian You should make an answer from that.

Answer (score 2):

Judas was posthumously voted off the Apostle Island:

> “For,” said Peter, “it is written in the Book of Psalms: “’May his place be deserted; let there be no one to dwell in it,’ and, “’May another take his place of leadership.’

So, no even though he was promised something he didn't get it. It's also worth remembering that Jesus is speaking to you and I in Scripture. Some would read that, in a sense, He offers us the same kingship if we are faithful.

Comment: That episode was a cliff hanger! 

Comment: Did St.Peter made a wrong judgment or reading of this passage in Psalm? Jesus was clear on Acts1:8 before that passage, "The Holy Spirit will give you power"...The Holy Spirit has not yet come, but Peter and the Apostles already chosen & lay hands on Matthias? This is too soon, that's why, Peter & Apostles must act only upon invoking the assistance of the Holy Spirit. Why? St.Paul is the twelfth Apostle not Matthias..

Answer (score 1):

Jesus did know that he was going to be betrayed and by whom.

> While I was with them, I protected them and kept them safe by that name you gave me. None has been lost except the one doomed to destruction so that Scripture would be fulfilled. John 17:12

God is a gracious God and is called Saviour many times. This is obviously distinct from Jesus being called saviour also. We could rightly say they are 'co-saviours' as each could not save on their own. God needed Jesus to die, Jesus needed God to accomplish his mission.

It is this grace in which He called Saul - the chief *persecutor of the church* and made him a pre-eminent Apostle!

> For you have heard of my previous way of life in Judaism, how intensely I persecuted the church of God and tried to destroy it. Gal 1:13

> The grace of our Lord was poured out on me abundantly, along with the faith and love that are in Christ Jesus. 1Tim 1:14

Judas had a pre-determined role to fill and this he did - according to the plan of God put in place eons ago. Being 'doomed to destruction' does not *have* to be an eternal penalty, but for this age alone.

We cannot presume to judge Judas by our standards of corrupt men and somehow rule him out of salvation - Jesus did die for all - Judas included. If there is a place for him - it is not clearly stated there is, just an inference, then that is for God to decide.

Comment: Great answer, If that passage in John17:12 refers to Judas as doomed, then,Jesus callng him a "friend" is the key why Jesus paid aleady the betrayal of Judas, and Jesus can save him even in hell. Judas, was indeed saved, and included in the salvation plan.

Comment: The son of perdition is the only one, of all the Father gave him, that was lost.  Lost. in this context, is over against "all thine are mine and all mine are thine...that they may be one as we are one".  Judas was not in Christ when he died.

Comment: You can only say that because you misunderstand the plan of salvation God has provided. The absurd idea of eternal suffering and associated theories have totally hidden the truth on this matter. God knows the cause of evil and He is fully capable of dealing with it without making it man's fault.

Answer (score 0):

*Did Jesus promise Judas a powerful position in the future kingdom of God?*

There was no passage on the bible that can support this question.

Judas was one of the chosen Apostles, but Judas did not made an "oath" during the Last Supper. The oath is like a Priest or Bishop receiving the full ordination from the hand of Jesus, consecrating them as a Bishop. Judas left the scene early, and did not made an oath to Jesus Christ.

> In the Gospel of John, **after the departure of Judas from the Last Supper**, Jesus tells his remaining disciples [John 13:33] that he will be with them for only a short time, then gives them a New Commandment, stating:[28][29] "A new command I give you: Love one another. As I have loved you, so you must love one another. By this everyone will know that you are my disciples, if you love one another." in John 13:34–35. Two similar statements also appear later in John 15:12: "My command is this: Love each other as I have loved you", and John 15:17: "This is my command: Love each other."[29]

> At the Last Supper in the Gospel of John, Jesus gives an extended sermon to his disciples.[John 14–16] This discourse resembles farewell speeches called testaments, in which a father or religious leader, often on the deathbed, leaves instructions for his children or followers.[30]

> This sermon is referred to as the Farewell discourse of Jesus, and has historically been considered a source of Christian doctrine, particularly on the subject of Christology. John 17:1–26 is generally known as the Farewell Prayer or the High Priestly Prayer, given that it is an intercession for the coming Church.[31] The prayer begins with Jesus's petition for his glorification by the Father, given that completion of his work and continues to an intercession for the success of the works of his disciples and the community of his followers.[31]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Supper

The departure of Judas is the key, why he cannot be consider a full pledged Apostle or a consecrated Bishop. And cannot be one of the Twelve described in the above passage. But Judas is definitely no longer in hell, after Jesus went in hell to preach the gospel. And the Catholic Church never teaches Judas was in hell, and if anyone or Catholic says, Judas is in hell, is a heretic according to one Archbishop.

https://catholicism.org/archbishop-paglia-says-its-heresy-to-say-judas-is-in-hell.html

In support of Ab.Paglia statement, this simple but realistic question is the key.Remember Judas is a friend of Jesus and Judas followed what Jesus commanded him to do on that night of betrayal.Jesus said to Judas, "go do it quickly.." and Judas obeyed..

*"If you were Judas, and you saw Jesus in hell, offering salvation or the infinite mercy of God, to anyone who will believe He is the Messiah, will you accept Jesus offering salvation, after feeling the pain of being in prison?"*

The answer If I were Judas is, Judas would definitely say to Jesus, ***"My Lord and my God, now I believe you are the Messiah, Son of the Living God, please forgive me.."***

And one more thing, Judas is not the Son of Perdition either in the passage below;

St.Paul is not pointing to Judas as the "Son of Perdition", because it was not yet revealed..

Douay-Rheims Bible

> Let no man deceive you by any means, for unless there come a revolt first, and the man of sin be revealed, the son of perdition."-2thessalonian2:3

Judas do not believe Jesus is the "Son of Man". Judas only betrayed Jesus looking unto him as "Rabbi" only.

> The Son of Man will go just as it is written about him. But woe to that man who betrays the Son of Man! It would be better for him if he had not been born.”

And in the gospel, Judas never profess that Jesus is the "Son of Man", Judas only look upon Jesus as a "Rabbi" and not the "Son of Man". Therefore, Judas may be "doomed" and cast down to hell or lost, but Judas was never the "Son of Perdition", because Jesus have a saving plan for all of his friends, including Judas.

> Greater love has no one than this, **that he lay down his life for his friends**. 14You are My friends if you do what I command you..(John15:13-14)

And Judas is a friend of Jesus, and Judas followed what Jesus had commanded in him, on the night of betrayal.

Judas left the scene, and did not profess an oath, and was not consecrated as Bishop during the Last Supper.

Comment: Might there be two entitled the son of perdition, much like God calling Ezekiel "son of man" and Jesus calling himself "son of man".  It's pretty hard to not understand Judas in John 17:12.

Comment: @MikeBorden Not pretty hard, esp, after Ab. Paglia stated, " In the Catholic Church, if anyone said, Judas is in hell, he is a heretic." Therefore, Judas is not the son of perdition, because, the Church is certain now, Judas is not in hell, the real hell of the damned souls.

Comment: The son of perdition in John 17:12 was lost **while Jesus was with them in the world**.  The son of perdition in 2 Thess. 2:3 appears on the scene **in the latter days, long after Jesus ascended**.  They cannot be the same and, in John 17:12 *lost* is over against *kept* (not lost).